# Add a Google Search Query String to a Bookmark

Tags: google-chrome, search, bookmarks

there guys, I am an SEO Consultant and I work with Google search operators a lot whether for technical SEO, Keyword research, or linkbuilding.

And, I see a training video where a guy had a few complex search queries saved as a bookmark on his chrome browser and I was wondering how he does it.

For example,

site:yourdomain.com -inurl:https

For a brief moment in one of the videos he showed part of the string and it looks like this...

```
javascript:window.location.href="https://www.google.com/search?q=site%
```

And, whenever he runs that bookmark, I can see on his browser that Google displaying this...

```
google.com/search?q=site:yourdomain.com%20-inurl:https
```

I tried to mess with the code to see if I can get the same result when manually running this search query...

```
site:yourdomain.com -inurl:https
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

---

*This question seems rather open-ended, so please forgive me if miss any information you are interested in or I go over anything you are already aware of.*

---

> For a brief moment in one of the videos he showed part of the string and it looks like this...

This is part of a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), which is essentially a chunk of JavaScript saved as a browser bookmark. `javascript:` is a pseudo-protocol and the portion after that is the JavaScript to be executed.

In the fragment given, `window.location.href` tells the browser to open a page to the URL in parentheses. For instance, ex.:

```
javascript:window.location.href='https://www.google.com/search?q=site:example.com+-inurl:https'
```

would open `https://www.google.com/search?q=site:example.com+-inurl:https`.

*General Bookmarklet Notes*

- Using `''` rather than `""` is important because this may cause the bookmarklet to fail.
- Theoretically, using [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) may be required in certain instances for the bookmarklet to work correctly.
- Any syntax errors broadly will likely cause the bookmarklet to fail (e.g. accidentally omitting the final trailing `'` or adding an extra `'` ex. `''`).
- This bookmarklet is *supported* in current versions of Firefox (latest version Firefox 77.0.1 - June 2020).
- This bookmarklet appears to be *unsupported* in versions of  Chrome newer than Chrome 74 (latest version Chrome 83 - June 2020).
- Doing some basic research, it wasn't clear to me if this lack of support in Chrome was a bug with bookmarklets in general (with an undefined time table to be fixed) or if there was another reason this bookmarklet didn't appear to work.
- The current version of Opera (June 2020) also appears to suffer the same issues as the latest version of Chrome.

> I see a training video where a guy had a few complex search queries saved as a bookmark on his chrome browser and I was wondering how he does it.

Running them by hand first and then extracting the relevant portions for later use, perhaps? The JavaScript in your original question isn't particularly special (as mentioned, it just opens a given URL). Hypothetically, there could be some additional code (ex. after the initial portion you've shown), but that is just speculation. (*See "Example Bookmarklet", below.*)

Most of what is contained in a "final" Google search URL after submitting a query is unnecessary for actually submitting a search query to Google via URL . For instance, if someone were to search for `example.com`, the resulting Google search URL might be:

```
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=y2j1XvCmMc64-gTa5obIBg&q=example.com&oq=example.com&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6CAgAEOoCEI8BOgUIABCxAzoFCAAQgwE6CggAELEDEEYQ-QFQipcBWJuoAWD9qwFoAHAAeACAAYMGiAGMJZIBDTAuMi4zLjEuMy4yLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEK&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiwuL-ywp7qAhVOnJ4KHVqzAWkQ4dUDCAg&uact=5
```

But the only value needed to *submit* the query via URL is the `q=` (query) parameter ex.:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=example.com
```

which is fairly easy to extract by hand.

As some notes on submitting Google search queries via URL:

- `?` is used to  pass variables to Google in the URL (i.e. to whatever back-end Google uses to actually conduct searches) and `&` is use to separate combined variables/values. So for the variables `variable1=123` and `variable2=456`, a URL might look like e.g. `example.com/script?variable1=123&variable2=456`.
- With Google and the `q=` (query) parameter, while you can use URL encoding for space characters in a URL (i.e. `%20`), Google specifically recognizes the `+` symbol in strings as spaces instead, which do not need encoding ex.:

  ```
   https://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+a+Google+search+phrase+with+spaces
  ```

**Example Bookmarklet**

The bookmarklet at the beginning of this answer is no different than simply creating a "normal" bookmark for ex:

```
   https://www.google.com/search?q=site:example.com+-inurl:https
```

which isn't very useful. However, it is possible to use additional JavaScript to, for instance, extract the domain name of whatever page you are browsing.

In this case, that JavaScript is called `window.location.hostname`. This can be substituted (almost) directly for ex. `example.com`. The basic form for [embedding JavaScript expressions within strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in JavaScript is:

```
'The value of a and b is ' + (a + b) + ' which is shown in this sentence.'
```

Following this guide:

```
'...?q=site:example.com+-inurl:https'
```

can be changed to:

```
'...?q=site:' + (window.location.hostname) + '+-inurl:https'
```

Note that the surrounding spaces aren't required and can be omitted ex.:

```
'...?q=site:'+(window.location.hostname)+'+-inurl:https'
```

The full version of the bookmarklet would then look like:

```
javascript:window.location.href='https://www.google.com/search?q=site:'+(window.location.hostname)+'+-inurl:https'
```

When this bookmark is clicked on any page, the value of the domain name (i.e. the hostname, as detected by the browser) for that page will replace `window.location.hostname` before the search URL is submitted to Google.

*Caveats*

The bookmarklet example given cannot be opened in a New Tab and retain its functionality, as the domain name (hostname) for a New Tab is blank (so the query submitted to Google is `site: -inurl:https`).

Answer (score 0):

That bookmark trick you mentioned can be a real time-saver.
You're on the right track with that code snippet. To make it work, create a new bookmark in your Chrome browser. Then, paste the JavaScript code you mentioned into the URL field. Give your bookmark a name like "Custom Google Search", and you're all set."

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly add a Google query string to a bookmark like you would with a regular URL. However, you can create a bookmark with a keyword in your web browser, which allows you to perform a Google search using that keyword.

Here's how to do it in most web browsers:

Visit the Google homepage.
Perform a search with the query you want to use.
Copy the URL from your browser's address bar.
Create a new bookmark in your browser.
In the bookmark properties, paste the copied URL into the URL field.
In the same properties, give the bookmark a name and a keyword (e.g., "g" for Google).
Save the bookmark.
Now, when you want to perform a Google search with that query, you can simply type your chosen keyword in the browser's address bar and press Enter.

For example, if you set the keyword as "g," you can type "g your_query" in the address bar and it will perform a Google search for "your_query."